# Version 28 is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recomand that you migrate to AndroidX libraies

Tags: java, android, android-studio

According [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html) to use Notifications I past this line of code 
        `implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"` to build.gradle file. But Android Studio underlines it by red and says: **Version 28(intended for Android Pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recomand that you migrate to AndroidX libraies when using Android Q and moving forward.** Can somebody tell me please what it means? I work with it only few days. This test project should be compatible with Android 5.0 so what is the problem with this documented back compatibility library? Here is the code from builde.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "web.php5.anotifikacie"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"
}
```

Comment: what do you think it means? It means you are using an old version, and it is recommended to move to a more up to date one. Consider the library version you use to be deprecated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Version 28(intended for Android Pie and below) is the last version of
>   the legacy support library, so we recomand that you migrate to
>   AndroidX libraies when using Android Q and moving forward.

[**`AndroidX`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) replaces the original support library APIs with packages in the androidx namespace. Only the package and Maven artifact names changed; class, method, and field names did not change.

You should use

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

You should follow [**`Release Notes`**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

Comment: Thank you. Is there any documentation about it? How could I know it?

Comment: @Čamo Sir, You should follow https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases